# ArangoDB AQL LIKE function does not use indexes

Tags: arangodb

Since the great devel version v2.7.0-rc1, we can use a like function.

That's awesome but how can one combine the new function with an index. I have tried the hash, skip-list and the fulltext index but no one is used by the explain function.

Any ideas?

Comment: LIKE() is around since a long time, you can find it in the [2.2 documentation](https://docs.arangodb.com/2.2/Aql/README.html). It created a JavaScript RegExp to match documents, but it has been replaced by a native code implementation. It still works the same however: a regular expression is created and used to match documents. RegExp can't utilize Arango indexes and will scan all documents that aren't filtered out by some other condition.

Answer (score 2):

The Fulltext index can only be used in the fulltext() function.
However, explain will not show you its using the index (its similar for geo indices)

fulltext() can use indexes only for doing prefix matches and complete matches.

As usual you should reduce your result set by other filters in advance.